# Microsoft TeamFoundationServer ExtendedClient Not compatible with Asp.Net Core 3

Tags: c#, tfs, nuget, asp.net-core-webapi, devops-services

This package is not compatible with Asp.Net Core 3 web api. Only .net framework :/.

Quick describe:
I am working on an custom web api project with asp.net core 3.0. The goal is to connect with TFS 2013 to create/update/event listener work items. 
I was trying to install :

```
Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient -Version 16.153.0
```

I prompt me with the following waring

> Warning NU1701 Package '**Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.2.3**' was
>   restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1,
>   .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7,
>   .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2,
>   .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework
>   '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0'.
>
> This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

I even posted in their site. Any workaround this ?(switch to .NETFramework is out of the list)
 Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient` package you are trying to use includes support for the older SOAP object model that is now end-of-line. Microsoft will not update this package any longer. As such it is very unlikely there will ever be official support for .NET Core.

Assuming your desired functionality can be realized with the modern REST API's, consider switching to one (or more) of modern REST-based packages documented at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/dotnet-client-libraries?view=azure-devops .

These are all NetStandard 2.0 and should work fine in your Core application.

As an alternative, you could call the REST API directly. It's a bit less convenient, but definitely feasible.

Comment: Oh! As correctly noted by CeCe Dong, you mention you are using TFS 2013, which doesn't (officially) support REST. While some bits are of the REST API _are_ present in TFS 2013, they are not supported at all, so switching to .Net framework for your client code is probably the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

Package `Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient` doesn't support very well for .Net Core framework. Since you want to work with TFS 2013, it's suggested to use .Net framework instead of .Net Core framework.

Answer (score 1):

LOL !

[image: Finger in your Ass]

source:
[Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient package doesn't have NetStandard support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/dotnet-client-libraries?view=azure-devops)

Comment: Yep, that's right